# When call child workflows, how to prevent circular dependency / infinite loop

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

I searched Google, StackOverflow and Github issues but did not find anything

https://docs.temporal.io/docs/java-implementing-workflows#child-workflows

It seems that I can easily create a circle with multiple workflows calling others as child workflow. A workflow can even call itself over and over again. Does Cadence/Temporal provide anything to prevent that or that is out of the scope?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create pretty deep child workflow structure. I don't see this being a problem. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent a loop when my team work on multiple workflows calling each other like: A->B->C->A->B.... It will never finish and blow up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not available yet. [Filed a github issue to address it](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal/issues/469).

Comment: Thank you! Limit depth is valuable but should we have circle detection or something about DAG?

Comment: It is actually absolutely valid for a workflow to create a child of the same type. For example to create a tree of workflows.